# Tab Clicking Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to follow this demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PP3x4crHBog however I couldn't name stuff the same cause I already named something else tab already, so I changed the variable names a bit and have the look and everything formatted, but whenever I click the login button the display doesn't show the login form....what did I do wrong?

```js
$('.tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
              alert("in");
              e.preventDefault();

              $(this).parent().addClass('active');
              $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

              target = $(this).attr('href');

              $('.tabs-content > div').not(target).hide();
              $(target).fadeIn(600);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='forms'>
            <ul class='tabs-group'>
                <li class='tabs active'><a href="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li class='tabs'><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class='tabs-content'>
                <div id='signUp'>
                    <h2 id='regTitle'>Register an account to get started!</h2>
                    <form id='regForm' name='regForm' method='POST' action='<?= BASE_URL ?>register/' style='display:block;'>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for='regUsername'>Username</label></td>
                                <td><input id='regUsername' name='regUsername' type='text'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for='regEmail'>Email</label></td>
                                <td><input id='regEmail' name='regEmail' type='email'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for='regPassword'>Password</label></td>
                                <td><input id='regPassword' name='regPassword' type='password'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                      <input type="submit" value="Register" style='margin:10px;'>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id='login'>
                    <h2 id='loginTitle'>Welcome Back!</h2>
                    <form method="POST" action="<?= BASE_URL ?>login/">
                        <input type='text' id='username' name='username' placeholder='Username'>
                        <input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
                        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign In'>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine. Make sure you include jQuery library properly.

Comment: Originally I had this <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= BASE_URL ?>public/js/home.js"></script> and I also included this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> just in case, but it's still not working and I also have other js code that works fine, such as form submission and alert pop ups if fields aren't filled

Comment: wowowoah. Thats not how you declare it.

Comment: add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the very beginning of your script, after `<!DOCTYPE html>` , `<html>`, and `<head>`tags are declared.

Comment: Add this in the `<head>` section of your html and check `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Kavidra you want to use jQuery 3.3.1 instead of 2.1.1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the script before the api was the one I included for the js code posted in the question.....I also included the script you showed before the original js I had and still can't get it to work. I apologize if I'm doing noob stuff I'm very new at this

Comment: You want to declare jQuery in the head instead of in the `<script>` tag where you are _writing_ your code. visit `developers.google.com/speed/libraries` to get all of your tags.

Comment: also check your edit I made your code into a snippet.

Comment: I do have that included in my header tpl which is the first thing I have before every page. header tpl, load correct body page tpl, footer tpl

Comment: in the snippet, your code works perfectly fine, apart from the fact you get a random alert of (in)

Comment: The alert was for debug purposes, would it matter if I'm using xampp to test in incognito mode? Edit: just tested in regular mode and still not working

Comment: Ok, ima put this into a jsfiddle to show you that this is working fine.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mhnaw7kv

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, but it really doesn't work for me for some reason. Uhh how do I give you a thumbs up or something

Comment: if you put a check mark under my answer you get like 2 reputation points and give me a thumbs up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mhnaw7kv is A good answer. It works, and yeah, so if you encounter any new problems just create a new question and I'll answer it.

```
//I have nothing to say
```

Just make sure to declare jQuery in the `<head>` tag of your code, the current one is `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Also, just a quick note, when you declare `<script>`, you don't have to put `<script type="text/javascript">`. Javascript is already declared in the `<script>` function, even if jQuery is declared.